# illegal start of expression error and difficulty compiling

Tags: java, error-handling

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class math
{
    private double xone,xtwo,yone,ytwo,x1,x2,y1,y2;
    private double distance;

    public void main(String[] args)
    {
        public distance()
        {
            setNums(0);
        }

        public setDistance()
        {
            setNums(x1,x2,y1,y2);
        }
        public void setNums()
        {
            xone = x1;
            xtwo = x2;
            yone = y1;
            ytwo = y2;
        }

        public void calcDistance()
        {
            distance = Math.sqrt((xtwo - xone)*(xtwo - xone) + (ytwo -            yone)*(ytwo - yone));
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String output = " ";
            output += "the distance is " + distance;
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why this program does not compile. the only errors are illegal start of expression and missing ; but I don't believe I am missing any ;

Comment: Are you familiar with java at all?

Comment: just starting I'm in high school

Comment: Maybe you try smaller code snippets first. Your variables have not been assigned values and you are calling functions with arguments that have no arguments in their declaration. I can recommend this book: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001805

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
public distance()
```

to

```
public math()
```

Constructor should have the same name as class.

Change

```
public setDistance()
```

to

```
public void setDistance()
```

Other than that,`setNums()` method definition shows that it does not have any parameters while you are passing them while calling it.

You have kept most of the methods inside `main`.Take them out and keep at same level.

I have made some changes so it can compile.Still you need to figure out what you are trying to achieve.

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class MathTest{
    private double xone, xtwo, yone, ytwo, x1, x2, y1, y2;
    private double distance;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public MathTest() {
        setNums();
    }

    public void setDistance() {
        setNums();
    }

    public void setNums() {
        xone = x1;
        xtwo = x2;
        yone = y1;
        ytwo = y2;
    }

    public void calcDistance() {
        distance = Math.sqrt((xtwo - xone) * (xtwo - xone) + (ytwo - yone) * (ytwo - yone));
    }

    public String toString() {
        String output = " ";
        output += "the distance is " + distance;
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend to capitalize the class name to following Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Your main(String[] args) needs to be static as well as public.